# confused about $\omega_{\pm}-$limit set of a subset X example

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am reading Ordinary Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems by G.Theschl, and I am confused about the definition of the $\omega_{\pm}-$limit set of a set $X \subseteq M$. 
The definition states that $\omega_{\pm}(X)$ is the set of all points $y \in M$ for which exists sequences $t_n \rightarrow \pm \infty$ and $x_n \in X$ with $\Phi(t_n,x_n) \rightarrow y$

Now, consider the system $\dot{x}=x(1-x^2)$, $\dot{y}=-y$.

Clearly, the $x-$direction has two stable fixed points at $x=\pm1$ and an unstable fixed point at $x=0$. It is also clear that the $y-$direction has one stable fixed point at $y=0$.

The author claims that $\omega_+(B_r(0))=[-1,1] \times\{0\} $, $r>0$.

It is clear to me that $(0,0),(-1,0),(1,0)$ are in $\omega_+(B_r(0))$.

However, I don't get why the whole interval $[-1,1]$ is also there.

For a given point in $[-1,1] \times \{0\}$, what would be the two sequences $t_n$ and $x_n$ that satisfy the definition?

I would really appreciate if someone can clarify this for me.

Thanks!

Comment: What is $\Phi?$

Comment: You probably mean p. 229 of the [University of Vienna preliminary version](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/ode.pdf)? Yes, this is (relatively) not hard to see when the reader makes use of Lemma 8.1 on p. 230! Namely, it follows from that lemma that $\Omega_+(B_r(0))$ is a compact *connected* invariant set. Now, the only compact connected invariant set containing $(0,0)$, $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ is just $[-1,1]\times\{0\}$. I will write the author about that.

Comment: @WilliamElliot See the (freely accessible) [University of Vienna preliminary version](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/ode.pdf).

Comment: If you want a more constructive proof, just pick $t_n = n$ and $x_n = \Phi(-n, \tilde{x}_n)$, where $\tilde{x}_n = (x_0, e^{-n})$. $\Phi(t_n, x_n)$ clearly converges to $(x_0, 0)$ for any $x_0 \in (-1, 1)$, $t_n \rightarrow +\infty$ and $x_n$ doesn't blow up and stays in finite part of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @Evgeny Ii would be good to formulate that as a full-fledged answer, together with showing that $x_n$ belongs to $B_r(0)$.

Comment: Thank you user539887 and @Evgeny. I like both of your answers. Now I get it. 
Thanks again!